# Do boost::lambda::bind expressions prevent in-lining / is there an alternate form that doesn't?

Tags: c++, optimization, boost, lambda, functor

As a matter of academic interest, does using bind templates (esp in boost::lambda) prevent in-lining? And if so, other than using declared functors, is there a boost::lambda form that does not prevent in-lining? (And especially in the latest gcc)

```
namespace bll = boost::lambda;

class MyItem
{
    public:
        float attribute() { return 4; }
}

struct AttributeLessConst
{
    AttributeLess( float value_a ) : value( value_a ) {}
    bool operator()( const MyItem & a ) 
    { 
        return a.attribute() < value;
    };

    const float value;
}

std::list<MyItem> myList;

remove_if_seq( myList, AttributeLessConst( 1.5 ) );        // in-linable // yes
remove_if_seq( myList, bll::bind(&MyItem::attribute, *bll::_1) < 1.5 );  // yes?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Nothing prevents inlining except for how advanced compiler* technology is. Unless Boost.Lambda resorts to type erasure, which it has no reason of using, everything it does can be inspected statically as easy as hand-written code. A relevant snippet in the [Boost.Lambda documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/lambda/s07.html#id2115713) suggests that the library delivers on this promise.

*: and/or runtime technology when considering not just programs but also e.g. shared libraries and dynamically loaded modules.

Comment: Point taken, but the documentation however uses very simple examples which don't use function pointers.

Comment: @Catskul My copy of GCC can inline in the presence of function pointers, although not always. What exactly do you expect?